# Modeling simple longitudinal data, unknown trend

Tags: generalized-linear-model, stan

Suppose I have many sensors recording a certain measure at discrete times (not too many times, something around 20/30 max). I want to get an idea of the average trend of the measure over time without necessarely fixing a functional form.

Would it make sense to simply have a param for each time and have partial pooling?

Something along the lines of

$$ Y_t \sim \beta_t + \text{other covariates}$$

With the betas coming, for example, from the same normal distribution.

Is there any major flaw/problem with this kind of simple model? Any good reason *not* to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is very similar to a [MMRM](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mmrm/vignettes/introduction.html), which would additionally account for the correlation of measurements over time (and do some implicit imputation of missing timepoints, which you would otherwise ignore). You may also want to consider whether there's an interaction between timepoint and covariates (e.g. the importance of a pre-experiment measurement will often decline over time).

You may indeed believe that the times are not too different, or perhaps that the size of a visit to visit change cannot be too large (forward-difference-parameterization). Additionally, it may indeed often be plausible that covariates have similar effects at different times, which you could reflect by having main effects and being skeptical on time point by covariate interactions being tool large. One way of encoding such things would be in a Bayesian fashion, which you could e.g. do with the `brms` R package (see [here](https://github.com/paul-buerkner/brms/pull/1435)).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm not very familiar with longitudinal models, now I have a starting point. As for the implementation, I'm probably going to use Stan

Comment: In that case brms may be very useful for you, because it uses Stan in the background (and you can obtain the code it generates using [`stancode`](http://paul-buerkner.github.io/brms/reference/stancode.html)).